# Openxml to write to excel not wrapping textbox value

Tags: c#-4.0, openxml

[image]

I am using Openxmlto write to excel uisng C#
It is writing in excel but if data exceeds textbox length, it is not wrapping up and coming to second line. Attaching screenshot for same.
How to wrap the same ?

```
ExcelOxml.SetCellValue(document, worksheet1, 5, 89, pricingmodel.PricingDetailExtended.PricingProductDetail.OpportunityId, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code to wrap the text in excel

```
//Create a cell format
CellFormat cellformat1 = new CellFormat(new Alignment() { WrapText=true});   
CellFormats cellformats = new CellFormats();   
cellformats.Append(cellformat1);
workbookstylesheet.Append(cellformats);
stylesheet.Stylesheet = workbookstylesheet;
stylesheet.Stylesheet.Save();
```